# Netbeans: Navigate -> Go to declaration?

Tags: ruby, ide, netbeans

I'm finding that with Ruby or RoR code, Netbeans' "go to declaration" doesn't show as lit up. Is there some way to turn this on?

Also: Eclipse with RadRails seems to have this for Ruby? RubyMine seems to as well... surely Netbeans can't be missing this normalish feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mouse right button->Navigate->go to declaration* should do it

Or, as I prefer, the shortcut ctrl+B.

Answer (score 1):

Also, ctl(or option in mac)-click over a method or var will browse to the declaration as well. I do it all the time in ROR project.

Comment: Okay, cool, it's just so limited. For instance, it cannot even find a helper method from a view. Both RadRails and RubyMine do this.

Answer (score 1):

And for those who are looking for shortcut for going back from "goto declaration" - key combination is

`alt + left`